# Label Figure in Latex

Tags: labels, nodes

I often have the need to apply leaders to a figure with some text. Right now I use Powerpoint with the Computer Modern Font and import the file to Overleaf in .pdf format. This workflow makes unappealing figures like the one below, because the text does not scale and is often hardly legible. Is there a way to label these figures right in Latex?

[image]

Comment: In LaTeX, a label is an internal identifier that is used to reference an image. Are you talking about the descriptive text with arrows inside the images?

Comment: Hi Miyase, I'm talking about the leader lines and descriptive text, such as the "load surface" callout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question isn't about putting pictures side-by-side, I'll answer with a single image. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelsep=period, subrefformat=brace}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw[->, >=latex] (-3,1) node[left]{Support}--(-1,0.5);
\draw[->, >=latex] (5,-1) node[right, text width=3cm]{CJP Weld\\ (Continuous Mesh)}--(1.5,0);
\draw[->, >=latex] (5,-1)--(1,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\label{fig:figure1} Description of figure 1.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

The usual command to display an image is included in a node so that, inside the `tikzpicture` environment, you have all the TikZ commands to draw arrows (and a lot more if need be).

It isn't a perfectly elegant solution since you have to go through trials-and-errors to find the best coordinates for each extremity of each arrow, but it does the job.

Comment: Thank you Miyase that is what I'm looking for. Hopefully this question is still on topic: Is there a way to use a CSV file to define the coordinates of the arrows instead of typing the coordinates as above?

Comment: I have no direct experience with it, but I'd start by trying the [`csvsimple`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) package. There are probably posts here about it. Otherwise, if you're using LuaLaTeX, you probably can open and read the CSV file with Lua inside LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you Miyase that is what I'm looking for. How can I draw on my figures using subfigures as below?

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Model Setup/T-Specimen/Model Setup - Annotated.pdf}}
    \subfigure[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Model Setup/T-Specimen/Idea Connection Isometric Picture.png}}
    \caption{(a) Abaqus Model (b) Idea Statica Model }
    \label{fig:CodeJoints}
\end{figure}

Comment: As this is a separate question, please open a new one (if necessary you can link this one in the new one).